# How to init and kill DUT between rspec files for a gem?

Tags: origen-sdk

I have a gem that supports two different libraries with a generic DUT model:

```rb
module MyGemLibrary
  module RSpec
    class DUT
      include Origen::TopLevel

      attr_accessor :force_import, :nick, :revision

      def initialize(options = {})
        options = {
          force_import: false,
          nick:         :rspec,
          revision:     :a0
        }.update(options)
        @force_import = options[:force_import]
        @nick = options[:nick]
        @revision = options[:revision]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have two rspec files:

```sh
myserver:ondie_devices $ ls spec
ringosc_spec.rb  spec_helper.rb  testtrans_spec.rb
```

What is the best known method for initializing the DUT and closing the DUT in each spec file?  When I used a local variable to store the DUT I got this error:

```sh
myserver:ondie_devices $ origen specs
[INFO]       0.010[0.010]    || OndieDevices: Loading ringosc model
Attempt to set an instance of OndieDevices::RSpec::DUT as the top level when there is already an instance of OndieDevices::RSpec::DUT defined as the top-level!
```

I have seen various ways of dong this but none seem to accomplish what I need done:

- prevent the error above
- Ensure Origen.top_level is initialized correctly such that theinstance attributes are readily available from within the gem code library.  E.G.

```sh
An error occurred while loading ./spec/ringosc_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: Pathname.new("#{tmpdir}/#{Origen.top_level.nick}_#{Origen.top_level.revision}_ringosc_#{data_type}.bin")

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `nick' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't manually instantiate multiple top-level objects, it needs to be done within the context of a target load/change.

The easiest way to do this for spec tests is by using anonymous targets - https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/runtime/programming/#Anonymous_Targets

```rb
  Origen.target.temporary = -> do
    DUT.new
  end
  Origen.load_target
```

That will also safely un-load any existing target (and its DUT) which will resolve your issue.

It is often common to do something like the above within a `before :each` block to reload the target between tests, or in a `before :all` block to have the same target loaded for all tests in a spec file.